# How to update an entity's particular field in google datastore

Tags: go, key, google-cloud-datastore, entity

I have the following struct:

```
type MyEntity struct {
 DSGeneratedID int64 json:"-" datastore:"-"
 Phone string json:"phone"
 Name string json:"name"
 Address string json:"address"
}
```

In the google datastore, I have stored as follows:

```
Name/ID:
id=5101067637358592 

Name:
Sandy

Phone:
9275939377

Address:
24, Nehru road, Chennai
```

Say, I want to change the phone number value. Now if I know the "key.id" value, I could use the following code and achieve what I want.

```
entity := publisher.MyEntity{
   Phone: "9472749280",
   Name: "Sandy",
   Address: "24, Nehru road, Chennai",
}
key := datastore.IDKey("Mine", **5101067637358592**, nil)

client.Put(ctx, key, &entity)
```

But for this I need this key **5101067637358592**. Now, if I know the name, address and old phone number, is there any way to get the key/id?

Or if there is any other way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

From a standard Task class

```golang
// Task is the model used to store tasks in the datastore.
type Task struct {
        Desc    string    `datastore:"description"`
        Created time.Time `datastore:"created"`
        Done    bool      `datastore:"done"`
        id      int64     // The integer ID used in the datastore.
}
```

You can get the key IDs from a query to the known fields.

```golang
var tasks []*Task

query := datastore.NewQuery("Task").Order("created")
keys, err := client.GetAll(ctx, query, &tasks)
if err != nil {
        return nil, err
}

// Set the id field on each Task from the corresponding key.
for i, key := range keys {
        tasks[i].id = key.ID
}
```

Then, update an Entity to Datastore using transactions.
From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#updating_an_entity).

```golang
tx, err := client.NewTransaction(ctx)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client.NewTransaction: %v", err)
}
var task Task
if err := tx.Get(taskKey, &task); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("tx.Get: %v", err)
}
task.Priority = 5
if _, err := tx.Put(taskKey, &task); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("tx.Put: %v", err)
}
if _, err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("tx.Commit: %v", err)
}
```

[All the code from Google golang samples for GCP](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query an entity without knowing it's key, you need to be able to construct a query by other fields of the entity that are indexed. To uniquely identify an entity, you would need a query that returns a single entity. This is typically done using a logical unique key field. Email of the user, for example, can be such a field.

Comment: I am able to construct a query and fetch an entity  and get all the other fields of that entity except "id.key"
because when I fetch it, it's coming as "0"
So either 1) How can I get the "id.key"?
(or)
2) I am able to get all the other fields of the entity other than "id.key". Now, how can I update one of those fields of that entity?

Comment: The Get/GetAll and Next APIs return the key. You can also implement KeyLoader interface (https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#hdr-The_KeyLoader_Interface) to get the key automatically populated into your entity.